# Is blessing a whip permanent?

Tags: phantom-abyss

Using a whip to collect a relic with rarity equal or greater to the rarity of the whip will bless the whip, which means that the whip no longer has any drawbacks. I originally assumed a whip would only remain blessed for a single run, but after having died (multiple times) in temples with blessed whips, they retained their blessed status. However, I've only tested this  with the uncommon green whips (since I haven't actually blessed any higher rarity whips yet), and higher rarity whips may behave differently than the lowest rarity whip. Plus I'm also wondering if a whips blessed status only lasts a set number of temple runs.

**Do whips maintain their blessed status permanently?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's permanent.**

Using the whip to get a relic of the same or higher level doesn't bless the whip but instead, removes the curse.
You can see many guides mentioning this curse, like [here](https://www.riotbits.com/phantom-abyss-all-whips-and-effects-guide-10141/) or [here](https://steamlists.com/phantom-abyss-detailed-information-all-wip-playthrough-in-phantom-abyss/), and it's also mentioned in the [Steam page](https://store.steampowered.com/app/989440/Phantom_Abyss/) in "About this game" section :

> Unlock new whips with success and choose from your collection before venturing into your next run. Each whips carries a minor blessing but also a curse that may complicate your attempt at riches and glory.

Once the curse is removed, it'll never come back, as supported by this [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/PhantomAbyss/comments/o7a3e0/curses_are_fun_let_us_play_with_them/) talking about a possible way to play again with cursed effect once they're removed.